# missing file saved by PowerPoint via AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, powerpoint

I saved the following content by **Script Editor.app** as `test.scpt`.
After I run the script from the terminal `osascript test.scpt`, PowerPoint starts up, opens the pptx file, and saved something (I can say this because the progress bar pops up).

However, I cannot find the saved file anywhere. Where is it?

```
on run argv
    set inputPath  to "/Users/myname/test.pptx"
    set outputPath to "/Users/myname/test.pdf"
    tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        activate
        open inputPath
        save active presentation in outputPath as save as PDF
        close active presentation
        quit
    end tell
    return "finished"
end run
```

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft PowerPoint 2016 for Mac` on `OSX Yosemite 10.10.3`

Comment: Works like a charm here (10.10.4 with Powerpoint 14.5.7). I had a little problem, because of too fast osascript. It didn't wait for PowerPoint to start. But if PowerPoint is already running everything is fine here.
I find the exported PDF at outputPath!

Answer (score 0):

Well you set the outputPath to your "Home" directory so It should be there but if you want a Chooseable save place and file you can use this script:

```
on run argv
set inputPath to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Choose a PPTX File")
set outputPath to POSIX path of (choose file name default name "MyPDF.pdf" with prompt "Choose a Location to save it")
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
        open inputPath
        save active presentation in outputPath as save as PDF
        close active presentation
        quit
    end tell
    return "finished"
end run
```

Comment: It worked for me, make sure you've entered in the correct directory, if it still doesnt work i suggest use "Automator", Automator is a built-in application where you can drag and drop simple actions in, you with have some convert Powerpoint to PDF options, You can save Automator Actions as Applications!, I found a website that will show you how: http://architechnic.net/architechnic/2012/11/1/automatically-convert-powerpoints-to-pdf-in-os-x-with-automa.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't save files to any folder. Use

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Powerpoint/Data/Documents
```

folder to save files from PowerPoint via AppleScript.

For example

```
set outputPath to "Documents/presentation.pptx"
```

It must be string (not POSIX path)